# MySQL error 1366 appears when leaving non-null columns with default values as blank

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure, mysql-5.5, cleardb

I am new to CodeIgniter and PHP in general. I made a new table with certain non-null columns. The non null columns all have defaults set according to their data type, so a VARCHAR has an empty string, while numeric types have 0 as default.

However, once I fill out the form (where I purposely leave the non-null columns blank to test them), and hit the submit button, it gives the following error:

> Error Number: 1366
>
> Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'salary' at row 1

It is inserting the double quotation marks for an empty string when it finds the user has not entered any value. I checked checked the mysql mode and it was turned to strict mode. However as I am using a multitenant DB (Azure-clearDB), they won't allow me super privileges and I cannot turn off the strict mode (or could I?)

Is there a way to turn off this mode, or is there any other workaround? I don't want to explicitly add an SQL if-else clause for each column, as that would be hard coded. Please help
The code is below:

CONTROLLER:

```
$additional_data = array(
                'first_name'    => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name'     => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'phone'         => $this->input->post('phone'),
                'salary'        => $this->input->post('salary'));

if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data))
        {
        $identity = $this->ion_auth->where('email', strtolower($this->input->post('email')))->users()->row();
        $forgotten = $this->ion_auth->forgotten_password($identity->{$this->config->item('identity', 'ion_auth')});
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
        redirect('auth/success', 'refresh');
```

MODEL:

```
    //filter out any data passed that doesnt have a matching column in the users table
    //and merge the set user data and the additional data
    $user_data = array_merge($this->_filter_data($this->tables['users'], $additional_data), $data);

    $this->trigger_events('extra_set');

    $this->db->insert($this->tables['users'], $user_data);

    $id = $this->db->insert_id();

    //add in groups array if it doesn't exits and stop adding into default group if default group ids are set
    if( isset($default_group->id) && empty($groups) )
    {
        $groups[] = $default_group->id;
    }

    if (!empty($groups))
    {
        //add to groups
        foreach ($groups as $group)
        {
            $this->add_to_group($group, $id);
        }
    }

    $this->trigger_events('post_register');

    return (isset($id)) ? $id : FALSE;
```

UPDATE: I am inserting multiple column values with the same insert statement.

Comment: Definitely include your code in the question. It help a lot with debugging. I'm guessing here but it sounds like you take whatever values inserted into the form and inject it straight into the DB. That generally is bad practice and you would want to sanitize and validate the input before you put it in the DB. Otherwise, it leaves room for SQL injections and attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your description, you have set the column 'salary' an integer column, but you insert `''` as an empty string.

so you need to set `0` instead of `''` in column 'salary'.

Comment: I have done that in the view, by setting the value attr as 0. But I'm not sure if that is good coding practice (i.e. changing the view). I'd rather the default value (which is 0) be inserted in case of a missing value, since the strict mode cannot be turned off

Comment: Actually, views are select query statements, we cannot insert data into them directly, but tables. And according your update, if you just insert the `$additional_data` into your table, you can precondition the `salary`, e.g.  `'salary' => (isset($this->input->post('salary'))&&(int)$this->input->post('salary'))?(int)$this->input->post('salary'):0`

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense! Thanks!